# transition page change with jQuery

Tags: jquery, transition

I am using the following code to show/hide "pages" on a one page site and wish to implement a transition/easing effect, to soften the page changes. Unfortunately this is beyond my feeble powers.

```
          <script>
              $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#page1").addClass("makevisible");
                $("#page1next").click(function () {
                    $("#page1").removeClass("makevisible");
                    $("#page2").addClass("makevisible");
                });
              });
          </script>
```

Any suggestions welcome and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.fadeIn and .fadeOut sound perfect for this kind of thing. They animate the opacity taking an argument for how long you would like the fade to last and handle the display attribute for showing/hiding from the DOM automatically as well.

http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/fading/

Code for transitions of half a second:

```
      <script>
          $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#page1").fadeIn(500);
            $("#page1next").click(function () {
                $("#page1").fadeOut(500);
                $("#page2").fadeIn(500);
            });
          });
      </script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply.

Comment: Also make sure you have position:absolute to the #page1,#page2 to make the animation smooth.

Comment: No problem - if this solved what you wanted, you can accept the answer with the checkmark on the left. I actually discovered fadeIn/fadeOut myself a few days ago when I got tried of always manually coding a simple transition effect like this and looked around.